# ggplot2 non-linearly adjust scale with color

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have two questions:

1. Although this data has a range from -1 to 5, most of them have a value between -1 and 1. Thus, I was wondering if I could adjust the relationship between result and color to be non-linear (that is, more change between -1 and 1, but less change between 2 and 5). Would this be possible using GGplot2?
2. How can I move the scale bar into the maps, say, in the bottom right position?

Here is my code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(data.table)
map<-get_map(location='united states', zoom=4, maptype = "terrain",
         source='google',color='bw')
ggmap(map) + geom_point(
 aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, show_guide = TRUE, colour=V1), 
 data=plot.data, alpha=0.3, na.rm = T)  + 
 scale_color_gradient(low="red", high = "red4", name = "Level")
```

Comment: I have edited your post: I have inlined the image (added a `!` before the description), fixed the list formatting and a few typos. You can improve this further by adding what you expect the code to do and how your current solution deviates from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `scale_colour_gradientn` and define `values` (from `?scale_colour_gradientn`: *if colours should not be evenly positioned along the gradient this vector gives the position (between 0 and 1) for each colour in the colours vector.*), e.g.:

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Sepal.Length)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c("blue", "red", "orange"),
                             values = c(0, 0.1, 1))
```

To change the position of the legend have a look at `?theme` > `legend.position` and/or `legend.justification`

Comment: Thanks to your advise. I have tried it. I still feel the colours are very hard to control. For example, when set

colours = c("blue", "red", "orange"),
                             values = c(0, 0.1, 1)
May I ask what does the values mean? does means "blue" lies in less than 0? "red" lies in 0-0.1? 
What if I want to set -0.5-0 to be grey, 0-1 to be red, 1-2 to be blue, etc?
Many thanks.

Comment: the values 0-1 do not represent actual values but the positions within the data range, e.g. if your data ranges from -1 to 5 and you'd like the colour positions to be at -1, 1 and 5 you'd use 0, 0.33 and 1. If your data ranges from -0.5 to 2 and you want the colours positions at -0.5, 0, 1 and 2 you'd use 0, 0.2, 0.6 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this command:

```
+theme(legend.position = c(xxx, xxx))
```

Answer (score 0):

Building upon beetroot's answer, one can write a short helper function to transform values on the original scale to the 0-1 scale used for plotting.

```
gradient_setter <- function(x, low = NULL, mid = 0, high = NULL){
  rn <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  (c(rn[1], low, mid, high, rn[2]) - rn[1])/(rn[2] - rn[1])
}
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Sepal.Length)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c("blue", "red", "orange"),
                             values = gradient_setter(iris$Sepal.Length, mid = 5, high = 5.8))
```